# Openshift Unable to locate persistence units

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openshift

I'm developing Hibernate JPA persistance web application, with my persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml (in war file it's in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF). It all works well on local Tomcat server, but when put on Openshift JBoss EWS, getting this message on startup:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistence.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at komante.server.SpringConfig.devEntityManagerFactory(SpringConfig.java:29)
        at komante.server.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17e4a4c6.CGLIB$devEntityManagerFactory$1()
        at komante.server.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17e4a4c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$55fcba01.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
        at komante.server.SpringConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17e4a4c6.devEntityManagerFactory()
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.XMLSchemaMessages
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:174)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport$7.run(SecuritySupport.java:166)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.SecuritySupport.getResourceBundle(SecuritySupport.java:166)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSMessageFormatter.formatMessage(XSMessageFormatter.java:70)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:398)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4145)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.reportSchemaError(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:721)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.getSimpleType(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:406)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseSimpleTypeDecl(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:163)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDSimpleTypeTraverser.java:104)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1442)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:630)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:617)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:575)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:541)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:252)
        at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:627)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.resolveLocalSchema(PersistenceXmlParser.java:435)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.v21Schema(PersistenceXmlParser.java:400)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:347)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:97)
```

Persistence.xml starts with

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">
```

and has two persistence units in it. I alse deleted hibernate.cfg.xml, both things suggested in other SO answers. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
The problem was I used `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit")` to create EntityManagerFactory and injected it in other Spring beans. 
Now I put

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit" />
    </bean>
```

directly in applicationContext.xml.
Still doesn't explain what was wrong with previous approach, but it works.